# How to achieve multiple reportitems in single expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, reporting-services, switch-statement

I want to use two reportitems in single expression on header part of the rdlc report.

I tried,

```
= IIF(ISNothing(ReportItems!R.value),ReportItems!R1.value,ReportItems!R.value)

= SWITCH(ISNothing(ReportItems!R.value),ReportItems!R1.value, 
       ISNothing(ReportItems!R1.value),ReportItems!R.value)
```

Also I tried by writing custom code function.

But I get,

> The Value expression for the textrun refers to more than one report
>   item. An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one
>   report item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is telling you all you need to know for this problem.  You are attempting to reference two report items, and this is not possible in the header or footer.

Have you considered putting your calculated value in the report body, and then referencing this from the header?

Considering the below example, I have set the value of RCalc to be your expression

```
= IIF(ISNothing(ReportItems!R.value),ReportItems!R1.value,ReportItems!R.value)
```

I have also set the visibility of RCalc to be hidden

Then the text box in the header instead only references RCalc

```
=ReportItems!RCalc.value
```

The design therefore looks like this

[image]

And when run gives this output

[image]

Is this the behaviour you were after, and is this applicable in your situation.  Pelease let me know if I can assit further.

**UPDATE**

The theory is the same when the values are coming from different Tablix.

Assuming the textboxes R and R1 are in totals Rows they can be referenced by RCalc in the same way.  Note they cannot be in the main row set of data

The layout like this has the textboxes (in Red Text) set at the bottom of the report outside of the row grouping/filtering.  These are R and R1.  Note in the output I have set their visibility to hidden.

[image]

This results in the output

[image]

RCalc can be a textbox *anywhere on the page* – it doesn’t have to be in a dataset.

Comment: Jonnus. R and R1 are coming from two different tablix. Sorry for not telling this in question itself. Each two tablix is referring two dataset. So where you want me to put Rcalc now ? Hope you understand my problem now. Thanks

Comment: Are R and R1 static cells (i.e. in a totals row perhaps) in each tablix?

Comment: No I believe. Here it's not mapped into group And I'm very new to this report concept. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can you update your original question with an image (uploaded to imgur) with your current layout, with R and R1 labelled.  It's difficult to know where the data is coming from otherwise with your current description of the problem

Comment: What you said in your answer is correct. The only change is, instead of calling from same tablix, here I'm calling from two different tablix. Consider like this, I'm having one header, below to that body which is having two tablix. Here my problem is, In my header part, one expression wants a calculated value from the two tablix. Hope your answer will solve my problem. But only thing I want to know is, where to place this piece of code(RCalc) ?

Comment: But why I'm getting error like, "report item expressions can only refer to fields within the same grouping"

Comment: Can I ask again then that you please share an image of the *report design* with R and R1 labelled. Thanks

Comment: I tried. Everything has been blocked in my company. I don't know how to tell you my problem exactly also. Anyhow thanks for your help. Your solution will help me definitely somehow. I will look into it deeply. Just confirm me, isn't possible to refer two report items in header part ?.

Comment: no - you will need to create a new item in the report (anywhere - set it to hidden) and reference that new item from the header

Comment: Okay thanks :-) +1 for clear presentation. And I will tell you once i done. Also I will ask you if I anything needed regarding this.